# iOS Password Autofill Suggesting New Password Instead of Existing

Tags: ios, passwords, autofill

I have Sign In and Sign Up forms in my app at startup.

Password Autofill keeps suggesting a "New Strong Password" for the *existing* password field. I'm explicitly setting the contentType to `.password` for the existing field and `.newPassword` for the new password field, yet iOS refuses to offer up anything but the "New Strong Password" View.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the View Hierarchy:

[image: View Heirarchy]

Here's how I'm setting the `textContentType` of each field:

[image: Setting the textContentTypes]

And this is what iOS does every time you tap the password field at Sign In:

[image: iOS Creating a New Strong Password]

Comment: What happens if you tap the email field, or enter something into the email field before moving to the password field?

Comment: @Paulw11 Same thing, attempts to populate with a new password.

Comment: I've now even gone so far as to create an entirely new view controller, with only an Email field, Password field, and Login button. Same result.

Comment: I tried to create a test project to look at this, but I just keep getting an error In the console that auto fill isn't available. From my server logs I can see that my device isn't even trying to read my site association file, so I don't know what I have done wrong; I have the entitlement set with my domain name 

Comment: It's 2020 and this is still a problem.

Comment: Same issue for me on iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

textfield content type `.newPassword` will actually suggest a new password instead of exisiting.
You should be using the textfield content type `.password` to get suggestion and autofill the password